# Show graph label when value is zero in amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm displaying a rotated bar chart in amCharts. I need to display the label for each bar, regardless of the value. If the value is zero, no bar displays so the label doesn't display. Is there a way I can always show the label, regardless of value?

Or better yet, is there a way that I can make the graph.labelOffset reference a function that will return a different amount depending on the value?

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wspencer/x0p462ft/) of what I'm working with. Notice that the 3rd item has a value of 0, so no label displays.

Here's the javascript code for the chart.

```
var gamingData = [
{
    "label": "1",
    "name": "Thinone",
    "grade": 30,
    "pounds": 3.6,
    "percentage": 2.3
},
{
    "label": "2",
    "name": "Studmuffin",
    "grade": 60,
    "pounds": 3.6,
    "percentage": 2.3
},
{
    "label": "3",
    "name": "Slacker",
    "grade": 0,
    "pounds": 3.6,
    "percentage": 2.3
},
{
    "label": "4",
    "name": "Momof2",
    "grade": 60,
    "pounds": 3.6,
    "percentage": 2.3
},
{
    "label": "5",
    "name": "TheVas",
    "grade": 120,
    "pounds": 3.6,
    "percentage": 2.3
}];

var displayGamingChart = function(gamingData, chartDiv) {
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart(chartDiv, {
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "dataProvider": gamingData,
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "Down [[pounds]]lbs and [[percentage]]%",
        "fillAlphas": 1,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        // "title": "Minutes",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "grade",
        "labelText": "[[name]]",
        "labelOffset": -75,
        "legendValueText": "",
        "fillColors": "#94BA65"
    }],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "depth3D": 20,
    "angle": 30,
    "rotate": true,
    "categoryField": "label",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "fillAlpha": 0.05,
        "position": "left"
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
     }
});
} 
displayGamingChart(gamingData, "gamingChart");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force display of labels, even those that do not fit, set [`showAllValueLabels`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#showAllValueLabels) to `true` in your graph's config:

```
"graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "Down [[pounds]]lbs and [[percentage]]%",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    // "title": "Minutes",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "grade",
    "labelText": "[[name]]",
    "labelOffset": -75,
    "legendValueText": "",
    "fillColors": "#94BA65",
    "showAllValueLabels": true
}]
```

As for the second part of your question, there's no function that would differentiate label offset for each bar individually.

Comment: do you know how to do the same with amcharts 4?